# Import error on Google oauth2client

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I installed the oauth2client using command line:

```
$ pip install oauth2client
```

but it gives me the above error when trying to run my application.

```
from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import OAuth2Decorator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/contrib/appengine.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import app_identity
ImportError: No module named appengine.api
```

I tried other solutions from Stack Overflow, but none of them solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda like I do, I would recommend install using the following commands in the command line:

```
conda install -c bcbio oauth2client=2.2.0
```

Or

```
conda install -c conda-forge oauth2client=2.2.0
```

The Anaconda help files for both of these suggest that they are compatible to a variety of operating systems, including PC, Mac and Linux.

Comment: I'm using Django with Eclipse